# Search for name and decimal numbers

Tags: excel, search

I've tried lots of searches for this but I'm still not coming up with anything that works.

I have a range of strings in Column A. I'm using the below two as an example

```
CCZTKGFWH862XED   Joe Lee Fake 062719 SAV 5,832.60
BDLPWVN7RVJ9UET   Joe Vaze  062719 SAV 1,000.00
```

My goal is to

1. do a search function to find within the string to find the decimal, and then return the whole number
2. return the name from the text. The problem is that some names have middle names, and other just first and last.

Could anyone explain how to accomplish this?

Using the below code I can extract the first name

`=IF(LEN(A19)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A19," ",""))=1,RIGHT(A19,LEN(A19)-FIND(" ",A19)),SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(TRIM(A19),(FIND(" ",TRIM(A19)&" ",FIND(" ",TRIM(A19)&" ")+1)-1)),LEFT(A19,FIND(" ",A19)),""))`

Using the below code I can extract everything after the first space

`=MID(A19, FIND(" ", A19, FIND(" ", A19)+1)+1,256)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number containing the decimal happens to be the last space-separated substring in the string.  So:

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",99)),99))
```

The Name occurs between the first space, and the first digit in the string:

```
=TRIM(MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,MIN(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A1&"0123456789",FIND(" ",A1)+1))-FIND(" ",A1)-2))
```

[image]